# Why doesn't my website show horizontal scroll bar on re-size?

Tags: html, css, resize

The page is http://conmifianza.com. When you resize the page, the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear.

The CSS:

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html,body,div,span,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,q,s,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,footer,header,menu,section{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0;
}
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    color: white;
    font-family: nexa_regular;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background:url("../img/fondo.jpg") transparent no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
}
.All{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.Head{
    position:relative;
    width: 1001px;
    height:120px;
    margin: 40px auto 33px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top:.7%;
    /*background-color:#00F;*/
}
#Logo{
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
    /*background-color:#090;*/
}
#content{
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 40px auto 33px;
    margin-top:.7%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#titulo{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 384px;
    height: auto;
    font-size:21px;
    text-align:right;
    color:red;
}

#contbody{
    width: 100%;
    height: 355px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:calibri;
}
#cont_slider{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:355px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/*.somos{
    background-image:url(../img/quienessomos/banner_01.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}*/
#image1{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    top:39px;
    left:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    z-index:999;
}
#contfoot{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 145px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
#menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 145px;
    position: relative;
    /*background: url('') transparent center no-repeat;*/
    border:none;
}

#socmed{
    width: 24px;
    height: 58px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    /*background: url('') transparent center no-repeat;*/
}
.menuitem{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 125px;
    height: 145px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty easy one you have `overflow: hidden;` set on the `.All` property. `overflow: hidden;` will hide anything outside of the current view.

Change your `.All` code to this:

```
.All {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;

 }
```

This was the change:

```
.All {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
/*overflow: hidden;   Remove this */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `min-width` in your css to the body will do the job.

> The `min-width` CSS property is used to set the minimum width of a given element. It prevents 
>   the used value of the `width` property from becoming smaller than the value specified for 
>   `min-width`.

Therefore, whatever you set the `min-width` to, say 1000px, as soon as the window gets less than 1000px the scroll bar shall appear.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: I'd avoid using w3schools as a reference; they often get a lot of things wrong. See [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) for why, and use an alternative like [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: I understand, and I'm not claiming that this specific context is incorrect. I am suggesting that you provide a different, better source, because, if this is the first source that Travis or others have seen, they may quickly develop the habit of using it as their primary source, which would be bad in the case of w3schools. Until w3schools starts to take accuracy (and other concerns) seriously, it shouldn't be willingly spread around on a site like this, which tries to serve as a complete reference for coding Q&A.